# How to change the type of an object property dynamically in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object that has some property, which I want to be able to set to either a `string` or a `number`.

```
const identityConfig = {
  [configID]: {
    metadata: {
      config: 'STATIC',
      value: null,
    },
  },
};
```

I want this `metadata.value` property to be either a number or a string, but with a default value of null.

I have this `identityConfig` object in another object, `ACCOUNT`

```
export const ACCOUNT = {
  name: '',
  identity: identityConfig
  setIdentityValue: (metadata: IdentityMetadata) => {
  identityConfig[configID].metadata = metadata
  }
  };
```

Here is the parameter type:

```
type IdentityMetadata = { config: string; value: string | number };
```

So I am making this `setIdentityValue` method public and using it to pass in the `metadata` property, which has a value property which will either be string or a number.

The problem is, this is the error i'm getting

> Types of property 'value' are incompatible. Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'null'.

How can I be able to set the value to either of those types, while ALSO giving it a default value of null? I have tried to change the `value` type in `IdentityMetadata` to be `string | number | null` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you haven't typed the `identityConfig` object, and so Typescript assumes *the types you create it with are the only types allowed*. This is called "[type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)" and means that this is also not possible:

```js
let foo = 3; // notice: no type provided!
foo = "hello!"; // `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`
```

What you need to do, then, is type the object!

```js
interface IdentityMetadata {
  config: string;
  value: string | number | null;
}

interface IdentityConfig {
  [key: string]: {
    metadata: IdentityMetadata,
  };
}
const identityConfig: IdentityConfig = {
  [1]: {
    metadata: {
      config: "STATIC",
      value: null,
    },
  },
};

export const ACCOUNT = {
  name: "Foo",
  identity: identityConfig,
  setIdentityValue: (metadata: IdentityMetadata) => {
    identityConfig[1].metadata = metadata;
  },
};
```

You can run this in [Playground and see for yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMLmGAngWQjDnTmOQG8BYAKGWQQHsQZgBzALmQGcwpQ2Ablr0AbnAA2AVwhde-EG2QAfZCCkBbAEbQVaqRInCaAX1q1QkWIhQYsYHLgDCzVkup1kAbQDWEXHJ8AgC6XB709BpEJGRwXHbYeITEpMTG9CbGZjRMILzIwJiJzq7s8UUOeC4s7MgAvJQi3gCMoY2ekdGpce0REbluXADkAMoAKgCCY6hOQwA0TX3i0rL6hgsdyCYbGRuZ5jQQAB4ADoxQYAzM+RNOTgDyAKoAcmP1vWpwUcMAYoyM8yahXsji4wOK1TcOx4RASlVwADVJDIuAAKKIpWLlEFJLqxACU9QAfB9wfDIewvK0AHQYmLkBp07pNbIZYy0IA).

Comment: I just recreated the problem in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJhAdsAlqAshYBDO2dQC8UA3lAMYD2iAZigOYBcUAzsAE4qL0DcUAbtgA2AVwjM2nblAA+URCIC2AIwjtZ8kUKEBfHgFgAUEaqI2UFAmRoQAYWp16RUkahQA2gEYAusxKu3KEUsXHxsPwDAigcGZgByAGUAFQBBJJhbOIAaSMDBUXFNbRzDKJ0St3KjPSMjCAAPMEp2YGizVpTbWwB5AFUAOSTnf1L5bGD4gDFKSmyAyyRUUGYF61B7WgYK1ix4RZsANWExZgAKYJw8HGY9tZBMS7CASiIAPhdR1aW7GPovbwAdBdQgRiMCrtgAjooQZjIYgA).

Comment: Thank you so much! Wasn't aware of type inference at all

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code

```js
const metadataValue: string | number | null = null; // Does compile
```

In typescript `null` is a value but also a type.
Allowing your value to be typed `null` does allow to initialize it with `null` as value.

> I have tried to change the value type in IdentityMetadata to be string | number | null but that doesn't work either.

What is the error ?
If `identity.metadata.value` is typed with `string | number | null` it should compile with `null` being assigned as value.

A common mistake is to expect `value` to always be assigned with `string | number` like :

```js
const display = (param: string | number): void => {
    console.log(param);
}

const value: string | number | null = null;
display(value); // Does not compile
```

Comment: If I turn `IdentityMetadata` into `{ config: string; value: string | number | null }`, the error I get is `Type 'string | number | null' is not assignable to type 'null'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'`.

Comment: Ensure that strictNullChecks is enabled: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks